# How to unlock toolbars in Eclipse 4.5 (Mars)?

Tags: eclipse

I don't see how  to unlock toolbars in Eclipse 4.5 (Mars). I read [this article](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fttoolbars.htm) and it says you can unlock them by right clicking. The only think I see by right clicking is:

> Restore Hidden Toolbar Entries

So what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

The locked toolbar causes all the icons to be scattered and it appears to be a common problem.   I solved it (similar to Iroume) by restoring perspective defaults and then restarting Eclipse.

That is Window->Preferences->General->Appearance.

Theme Windows
Color and Font theme (Classic)

Click Restore Defaults then restart.

Answer (score -1):

Go to window->preferences->General->Appearance

Now select a theme and color and font theme. Restart the eclipse and the toolbar should be unlocked.

[image: Eclipse]

Comment: the fix i used is Windows>General>Appearence then click the Restaure Defaults Button at the bottom